# Readiness and liveness failed with smallrye metrics in kubernetes

Tags: java, kubernetes, quarkus, metrics, smallrye

I'm deploying a pod written in quarkus in kubernetes and the startup seems to go fine. But there's a problem with readiness and liveness that result unhealthy.
For metrics I'm using smallrye metrics configured on port 8080 and on path:

```
quarkus.smallrye-metrics.path=/metrics
```

If i enter in the pod and i execute

```
curl localhost:8080/metrics
```

the response is

```
# HELP base_classloader_loadedClasses_count Displays the number of classes that are currently loaded in the Java virtual machine.
# TYPE base_classloader_loadedClasses_count gauge
base_classloader_loadedClasses_count 7399.0
# HELP base_classloader_loadedClasses_total Displays the total number of classes that have been loaded since the Java virtual machine has started execution.
# TYPE base_classloader_loadedClasses_total counter
base_classloader_loadedClasses_total 7403.0
# HELP base_classloader_unloadedClasses_total Displays the total number of classes unloaded since the Java virtual machine has started execution.
# TYPE base_classloader_unloadedClasses_total counter
base_classloader_unloadedClasses_total 4.0
# HELP base_cpu_availableProcessors Displays the number of processors available to the Java virtual machine. This value may change during a particular invocation of the virtual machine.
# TYPE base_cpu_availableProcessors gauge
base_cpu_availableProcessors 1.0
# HELP base_cpu_processCpuLoad_percent Displays  the "recent cpu usage" for the Java Virtual Machine process. This value is a double in the [0.0,1.0] interval. A value of 0.0 means that none of the CPUs were running threads from the JVM process during the recent period of time observed, while a value of 1.0 means that all CPUs were actively running threads from the JVM 100% of the time during the recent period being observed. Threads from the JVM include the application threads as well as the JVM internal threads. All values between 0.0 and 1.0 are possible depending of the activities going on in the JVM process and the whole system. If the Java Virtual Machine recent CPU usage is not available, the method returns a negative value.
# TYPE base_cpu_processCpuLoad_percent gauge
base_cpu_processCpuLoad_percent 2.3218608761411404E-7
# HELP base_cpu_systemLoadAverage Displays the system load average for the last minute. The system load average is the sum of the number of runnable entities queued to the available processors and the number of runnable entities running on the available processors averaged over a period of time. The way in which the load average is calculated is operating system specific but is typically a damped time-dependent average. If the load average is not available, a negative value is displayed. This attribute is designed to provide a hint about the system load and may be queried frequently. The load average may be unavailable on some platforms where it is expensive to implement this method.
# TYPE base_cpu_systemLoadAverage gauge
base_cpu_systemLoadAverage 0.15
# HELP base_gc_time_total Displays the approximate accumulated collection elapsed time in milliseconds. This attribute displays -1 if the collection elapsed time is undefined for this collector. The Java virtual machine implementation may use a high resolution timer to measure the elapsed time. This attribute may display the same value even if the collection count has been incremented if the collection elapsed time is very short.
# TYPE base_gc_time_total counter
base_gc_time_total_seconds{name="Copy"} 0.032
base_gc_time_total_seconds{name="MarkSweepCompact"} 0.071
# HELP base_gc_total Displays the total number of collections that have occurred. This attribute lists -1 if the collection count is undefined for this collector.
# TYPE base_gc_total counter
base_gc_total{name="Copy"} 4.0
base_gc_total{name="MarkSweepCompact"} 2.0
# HELP base_jvm_uptime_seconds Displays the time from the start of the Java virtual machine in milliseconds.
# TYPE base_jvm_uptime_seconds gauge
base_jvm_uptime_seconds 624.763
# HELP base_memory_committedHeap_bytes Displays the amount of memory in bytes that is committed for the Java virtual machine to use. This amount of memory is guaranteed for the Java virtual machine to use.
# TYPE base_memory_committedHeap_bytes gauge
base_memory_committedHeap_bytes 8.5262336E7
# HELP base_memory_maxHeap_bytes Displays the maximum amount of heap memory in bytes that can be used for memory management. This attribute displays -1 if the maximum heap memory size is undefined. This amount of memory is not guaranteed to be available for memory management if it is greater than the amount of committed memory. The Java virtual machine may fail to allocate memory even if the amount of used memory does not exceed this maximum size.
# TYPE base_memory_maxHeap_bytes gauge
base_memory_maxHeap_bytes 1.348141056E9
# HELP base_memory_usedHeap_bytes Displays the amount of used heap memory in bytes.
# TYPE base_memory_usedHeap_bytes gauge
base_memory_usedHeap_bytes 1.2666888E7
# HELP base_thread_count Displays the current number of live threads including both daemon and non-daemon threads
# TYPE base_thread_count gauge
base_thread_count 11.0
# HELP base_thread_daemon_count Displays the current number of live daemon threads.
# TYPE base_thread_daemon_count gauge
base_thread_daemon_count 7.0
# HELP base_thread_max_count Displays the peak live thread count since the Java virtual machine started or peak was reset. This includes daemon and non-daemon threads.
# TYPE base_thread_max_count gauge
base_thread_max_count 11.0
# HELP vendor_cpu_processCpuTime_seconds Displays the CPU time used by the process on which the Java virtual machine is running in nanoseconds. The returned value is of nanoseconds precision but not necessarily nanoseconds accuracy. This method returns -1 if the the platform does not support this operation.
# TYPE vendor_cpu_processCpuTime_seconds gauge
vendor_cpu_processCpuTime_seconds 4.36
# HELP vendor_cpu_systemCpuLoad_percent Displays the "recent cpu usage" for the whole system. This value is a double in the [0.0,1.0] interval. A value of 0.0 means that all CPUs were idle during the recent period of time observed, while a value of 1.0 means that all CPUs were actively running 100% of the time during the recent period being observed. All values betweens 0.0 and 1.0 are possible depending of the activities going on in the system. If the system recent cpu usage is not available, the method returns a negative value.
# TYPE vendor_cpu_systemCpuLoad_percent gauge
vendor_cpu_systemCpuLoad_percent 2.3565253563367224E-7
# HELP vendor_memory_committedNonHeap_bytes Displays the amount of non heap memory in bytes that is committed for the Java virtual machine to use.
# TYPE vendor_memory_committedNonHeap_bytes gauge
vendor_memory_committedNonHeap_bytes 5.1757056E7
# HELP vendor_memory_freePhysicalSize_bytes Displays the amount of free physical memory in bytes.
# TYPE vendor_memory_freePhysicalSize_bytes gauge
vendor_memory_freePhysicalSize_bytes 5.44448512E9
# HELP vendor_memory_freeSwapSize_bytes Displays the amount of free swap space in bytes.
# TYPE vendor_memory_freeSwapSize_bytes gauge
vendor_memory_freeSwapSize_bytes 0.0
# HELP vendor_memory_maxNonHeap_bytes Displays the maximum amount of used non-heap memory in bytes.
# TYPE vendor_memory_maxNonHeap_bytes gauge
vendor_memory_maxNonHeap_bytes -1.0
# HELP vendor_memory_usedNonHeap_bytes Displays the amount of used non-heap memory in bytes.
# TYPE vendor_memory_usedNonHeap_bytes gauge
vendor_memory_usedNonHeap_bytes 4.7445384E7
# HELP vendor_memoryPool_usage_bytes Current usage of the memory pool denoted by the 'name' tag
# TYPE vendor_memoryPool_usage_bytes gauge
vendor_memoryPool_usage_bytes{name="CodeHeap 'non-nmethods'"} 1357184.0
vendor_memoryPool_usage_bytes{name="CodeHeap 'non-profiled nmethods'"} 976128.0
vendor_memoryPool_usage_bytes{name="CodeHeap 'profiled nmethods'"} 4787200.0
vendor_memoryPool_usage_bytes{name="Compressed Class Space"} 4562592.0
vendor_memoryPool_usage_bytes{name="Eden Space"} 0.0
vendor_memoryPool_usage_bytes{name="Metaspace"} 3.5767632E7
vendor_memoryPool_usage_bytes{name="Survivor Space"} 0.0
vendor_memoryPool_usage_bytes{name="Tenured Gen"} 9872160.0
# HELP vendor_memoryPool_usage_max_bytes Peak usage of the memory pool denoted by the 'name' tag
# TYPE vendor_memoryPool_usage_max_bytes gauge
vendor_memoryPool_usage_max_bytes{name="CodeHeap 'non-nmethods'"} 1369600.0
vendor_memoryPool_usage_max_bytes{name="CodeHeap 'non-profiled nmethods'"} 976128.0
vendor_memoryPool_usage_max_bytes{name="CodeHeap 'profiled nmethods'"} 4793088.0
vendor_memoryPool_usage_max_bytes{name="Compressed Class Space"} 4562592.0
vendor_memoryPool_usage_max_bytes{name="Eden Space"} 2.3658496E7
vendor_memoryPool_usage_max_bytes{name="Metaspace"} 3.5769312E7
vendor_memoryPool_usage_max_bytes{name="Survivor Space"} 2883584.0
vendor_memoryPool_usage_max_bytes{name="Tenured Gen"} 9872160.0
```

So it seems metrics are working fine, but kubernetes returns this error:

```
Warning  Unhealthy  24m (x9 over 28m)    kubelet            Liveness probe errored: strconv.Atoi: parsing "metrics": invalid syntax
  Warning  Unhealthy  4m2s (x70 over 28m)  kubelet            Readiness probe errored: strconv.Atoi: parsing "metrics": invalid syntax
```

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: check https://quarkus.io/guides/deploying-to-kubernetes#add-readiness-and-liveness-probes

Comment: I've used that link to set all the configs and the error reported in my first post derives from that work. I've also checked https://quarkus.io/guides/smallrye-health but I can't find a solution

Comment: can you put a reproducer to github ?

Comment: here you are:
https://github.com/gigallo/app-version-checker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I needed to fix dockerfile.jvm

```
FROM openjdk:11

ENV LANG='en_US.UTF-8' LANGUAGE='en_US:en'

# We make four distinct layers so if there are application changes the library layers can be re-used
# RUN ls -la target
COPY --chown=185 target/quarkus-app/lib/ /deployments/lib/
COPY --chown=185 target/quarkus-app/*.jar /deployments/
COPY --chown=185 target/quarkus-app/app/ /deployments/app/
COPY --chown=185 target/quarkus-app/quarkus/ /deployments/quarkus/
RUN java -version

EXPOSE 8080
USER root
ENV AB_JOLOKIA_OFF=""
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0 -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"
ENV JAVA_DEBUG="true"
ENV JAVA_APP_JAR="/deployments/quarkus-run.jar"

CMD java ${JAVA_OPTS} -jar ${JAVA_APP_JAR}
```

this way jar started working. without that CMD openjdk image is just starting jshell. After that I saw the log below

```
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
2022-09-21 19:56:00,450 INFO  [io.sma.health] (executor-thread-1) SRHCK01001: Reporting health down status: {"status":"DOWN","checks":[{"name":"Database connections health check","status":"DOWN","data":{"<default>":"Unable to execute the validation check for the default DataSource: Communications link failure\n\nThe last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server."}}]}
```

DB connection in kubernetes is not working.

deploy command: mvn clean package -DskipTests -Dquarkus.kubernetes.deploy=true

"minikube dashboard" looks like below
[image: minikube dashboard]

used the endpoints below

```
quarkus.smallrye-health.root-path=/health
quarkus.smallrye-health.liveness-path=/health/live
quarkus.smallrye-metrics.path=/metrics
```

and liveness url looks like below in the firefox
[image: quarkus liveness]

I needed to change some dependencies in pom because I use minikube in my local and needed to delete some java code because of db connection problems, you can find working example at https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/quarkus-examples/tree/master/liveness-readiness-kubernetes

you can see the definition yaml of the deployment below.

```
mintozzy@mintozzy-MACH-WX9:~$ kubectl get deployments.apps app-version-checker -o yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    app.quarkus.io/build-timestamp: 2022-09-21 - 20:29:23 +0000
    app.quarkus.io/commit-id: 7d709651868d810cd9a906609c8edad3f9d796c0
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "3"
    prometheus.io/path: /metrics
    prometheus.io/port: "8080"
    prometheus.io/scheme: http
    prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
  creationTimestamp: "2022-09-21T20:13:21Z"
  generation: 3
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: app-version-checker
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  name: app-version-checker
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "117584"
  uid: 758d420b-ed22-48f8-9d6f-150422a6b38e
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: app-version-checker
      app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        app.quarkus.io/build-timestamp: 2022-09-21 - 20:29:23 +0000
        app.quarkus.io/commit-id: 7d709651868d810cd9a906609c8edad3f9d796c0
        prometheus.io/path: /metrics
        prometheus.io/port: "8080"
        prometheus.io/scheme: http
        prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: app-version-checker
        app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        image: mintozzy/app-version-checker:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /health/live
            port: 8080
            scheme: HTTP
          periodSeconds: 30
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 10
        name: app-version-checker
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: http
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /health/ready
            port: 8080
            scheme: HTTP
          periodSeconds: 30
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 10
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
status:
  availableReplicas: 1
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: "2022-09-21T20:13:21Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2022-09-21T20:30:03Z"
    message: ReplicaSet "app-version-checker-5cb974f465" has successfully progressed.
    reason: NewReplicaSetAvailable
    status: "True"
    type: Progressing
  - lastTransitionTime: "2022-09-22T16:09:48Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2022-09-22T16:09:48Z"
    message: Deployment has minimum availability.
    reason: MinimumReplicasAvailable
    status: "True"
    type: Available
  observedGeneration: 3
  readyReplicas: 1
  replicas: 1
  updatedReplicas: 1
```

Comment: Sorry, but the only important change I see is quarkus.smallrye-health.liveness-path=/health/live. The rest is similar to my application, that is running fine in kubernetes with the health checks disabled. But obviously I want health checks running. Maybe your minikube does not run health checks?

Comment: added the yml at the bottom. I had error if DB is enabled. it means health checks has been active :)

Comment: Sorry for the big delay in my answer but only yesterday I found the time to put my fat hands again on the project. Yeah, you are right...I didn't see my docker was missing of last cdm java command. So your answer is correct and a +1 is deserved

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer is better just FYI